# How to find out which key is pressed in keyDown event in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing my first visual basic program, And I want to do something when for example the 'k' button is pressed, I know that I should write the code in "KeyDown" event, but I don't know how to find out that 'k' button is pressed or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a Windows Forms Application, you have to put the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `True` so the form will monitorize key events.

Then:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "k" OrElse e.KeyChar = "K" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed!")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you prefer, you could use other event:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.K Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It says that KeyChar is not a member of e!
I used KeyValue and it worked!

Comment: @Navid777 KeyPressEventArgs has a member called KeyChar, you probably used KeyEventArgs. There are different events and "e" has two different types on each one. Pay attention to the code. Glad to help!